# How to debug asp.net controller bespoke class object thats passed as JSON

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

How can I debug the following controller code to check what is being populated in the `pagedData` variable? `pagedData` should be of type `pagedData` as this is the `Pagination.PagedResult` output. `pagedData` should contain a list and two integer values. How could I return the contents of `pagedData` to the console after it has been populated? I can't debug the javascript function as it's not entering the `getJSON` section, the issue appears to be in the controller. Ideally I want to see the JSON that is being sent back from the controller to the view.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CogntionCM.Models;
using CogntionCM.Helper;

namespace CCM.Controllers
{
    public class RetailersController : Controller
    {
        private MCDEntities context = new MCDEntities();

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult GetPagedData(int pageNumber = 1, int pageSize = 20)
        {
            List<Retailer> listData = context.Retailers.ToList();
            var pagedData = Pagination.PagedResult(listData, pageNumber, pageSize);
            return Json(pagedData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

The controller makes use of two `Helpers` as follows:

PagedData.cs

```
namespace CCM.Helper
{
    public class PagedData<T> where T : class
    {
        public IEnumerable<T> Data { get; set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; set; }
        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Pagination.cs

```
namespace CCM.Helper
{
    public static class Pagination
    {
        public static PagedData<T> PagedResult<T>(this List<T> list, int PageNumber, int PageSize) where T : class
        {
            var result = new PagedData<T>();
            result.Data = list.Skip(PageSize * (PageNumber - 1)).Take(PageSize).ToList();
            result.TotalPages = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)list.Count() / PageSize));
            result.CurrentPage = PageNumber;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

The following is the Retailers Model:

```
namespace CCM.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class Retailer
    {
        public int RetailerID { get; set; }
        public string RetailerCode { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        ...lots more columns...
        public virtual Retailer_Statuses Retailer_Statuses { get; set; }
        public virtual Retailer_Types Retailer_Types { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The following javascript is on the Retailers/Index page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    GetPageData(1, 20);
});
function GetPageData(pageNum, pageSize) {
    $("#tblData").empty();
    $("#paged").empty();;
    $.getJSON("/Retailers/Index/GetPagedData", { pageNumber: pageNum, pageSize: pageSize }, function (response) {
        var rowData = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < response.Data.length; i++) {
            rowData = rowData + '<tr><td>' + response.Data[i].Name + '</td><td>' + response.Data[i].RetailerCode + '</td></tr>';
        }
        $("#tblData").append(rowData);
        PagingTemplate(response.TotalPages, response.CurrentPage);
    });
};
```

Comment: Log it into the console. Use a debug pointer to stop execution on the variable and view it.

Comment: Thanks, I added a breakpoint in the debugger in the console before and after the `getJSON` and it appears the `response` is `undefined`. So I need to see in the controller before the JSON is sent back to the view, is this possible?

Comment: Why not?? Add a breakpoint, check value whenever you are calling an external service.